# How do I send a JSON file to UE5 using Socket.IO?

Tags: json, server, socket.io, unreal-engine5

Before I explain what I need to do, I want to say I'm not a programmer. I know a bit of C, C++, and C #. This is a college project that I need to finish soon, and I've been struggling to solve it for a few days now. We are coding in Python, which is a programming language I haven't used before, and creating a server with javascript (using node.js). I am using the newest version of UE 5.3 and SocketIOClient-v2.7.1-UE5.3.

We were tasked to write a code in Python that uses the camera for motion capture. The body part I chose to track was the irises. I did this using Mediapipe and stored the coordinates in a Python dictionary, which I later transformed into a JSON file. I used a tutorial on how to make a server using SocketIO.

This is the tutorial I used: https://medium.com/@slonorib/how-to-connect-unreal-engine-4-to-local-server-via-sockets-9d73fd180f0b

Of course, I adapted some things in Unreal for 5.3, but the code in .js is the same. I then changed the function which sent random numbers to unreal to:

```
function getDictionary() {
fs.readFile('dictionary.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
if (err) {
console.error('Error:', err);
return;
}
const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(jsonData);
return data;
});
}
function sendBlink() {
console.log('Json sent to user');
io.emit('import json', getDictionary());
}setInterval(sendBlink, 3000);
```

When I start the server, I get the message in Unreal that it's connected, but it does not print the string. You can see how the blueprint looks in the tutorial.

To give you an example of how my JSON file looks like: `{"0": {"x": 392, "y": 232, "blink": 3}}`

As you can see, I have three values that I would like to use in UE. X and Y are supposed to rotate the camera, and for every blink, the character is supposed to take one step. I have a rough blueprint for testing, but I need to get these values to finish it.

I tried using socket.io-parser, but I can't really wrap my head around it. I looked all over the internet, but every tutorial I could find simply writes an example JSON instead of getting the already existing file.

I don't usually ask for help on stackoverflow, but my professor hasn't been answering my emails, even though she promised to send me the solution for this. I have A LOT of other projects to do, and I'm running out of time.

Please help.